# Canvas multiple bouncing squares - Clearing Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've created a little bouncing boxes demo in javascript using the canvas. Each box (for want of a better word) class handles it's own updates and rendering. However, my problem lies in clearing the canvas before drawing the next frame. It clears fine when the boxes are moving but leaves artifacts behind after it hits a wall. Here's a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dzuvL7ph/1/

Here's my code;

```
function init(){
    window.box1 = new Box(50, 'red', 0, 0);
    window.box2 = new Box(50, 'blue', 400, 20);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function update() {
    window.box1.update();
    window.box2.update();

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function render() {
    window.box1.render();
    window.box2.render();
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// --
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var Box = function(dimensions, color, x, y){
    this.width = dimensions;
    this.height = dimensions;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.velocityX = 10;
    this.velocityY = 10;
    this.color = color;
    this.context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

    this.update = function(){
        this.x += this.velocityX;
        this.y += this.velocityY;
        this.collisionCheck();
    };
    this.render = function(){
        this.context.fillStyle = this.color;
        this.context.clearRect(this.x  - this.velocityX, this.y - this.velocityY, this.width, this.height);
        this.context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    };
    this.collisionCheck = function(){
        if(this.y > 600 - this.height || this.y < 0)
            this.velocityY *= -1;
        if(this.x > 800 - this.width || this.x < 0)
            this.velocityX *= -1;
    };
};
```

I assume it's to do with `this.context.clearRect(this.x  - this.velocityX, this.y - this.velocityY, this.width, this.height);` but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try clearing entire canvas using `this.context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`. But it will affect the performance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little weird you're doing a cleanup for each box. Normally, you'd wipe the whole `canvas` on each frame: https://jsfiddle.net/yb58fd47/

### WHY it happens

Your `update` function checks for collisions, which can in turn reverse the speed component(s). But, your `render` function relies on that speed component to accurately represent the last speed. If you don't want to clear the whole canvas, you can keep track of the previous **actual** speed the box had (I added `velocityXLast` and `velocityYLast`):

```js
function init(){
    window.box1 = new Box(50, 'red', 0, 0);
    window.box2 = new Box(50, 'blue', 120, 20);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function update() {
    window.box1.update();
    window.box2.update();
  
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function render() {
    window.box1.render();
    window.box2.render();
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// --
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var Box = function(dimensions, color, x, y){
    this.width = dimensions;
    this.height = dimensions;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.velocityX = 10;
    this.velocityY = 10;
    this.color = color;
    this.context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

    this.update = function(){
        this.x += this.velocityX;
        this.y += this.velocityY;
        this.velocityXLast = this.velocityX;
        this.velocityYLast = this.velocityY;
        this.collisionCheck();
    };
    this.render = function(){
        this.context.fillStyle = this.color;
        this.context.clearRect(this.x  - this.velocityXLast, this.y - this.velocityYLast, this.width, this.height);
        this.context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    };
    this.collisionCheck = function(){
        if(this.y > 150 - this.height || this.y < 0)
            this.velocityY *= -1;
        if(this.x > 400 - this.width || this.x < 0)
            this.velocityX *= -1;
    };
};

init();
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid black}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="150"></canvas>
```

Comment: I'll update this answer with the explanation of why you're getting those artifacts.

Comment: Thanks! I tried a full canvas clear on every render, however It would either only render one box or render nothing. I couldn't get the clear/draw order working properly

Comment: Yup, I'm just writing an update, but clearing the canvas is a standard thing to do. Imagine if there was a background on canvas - you'd have no way of animating those boxes without regenerating the boxes AND the background on each frame.

Comment: @Shomz Ah, okay, that makes a lot of sense, thank you! Nice trick clearing the canvas by resetting the width on each update, didn't know that was possible.

Comment: @Lewis, it's very important **when** you are clearing the canvas. Since you were getting only one box to render, I'd imagine you were clearing it inside one of the boxes' methods, which is why the last box will wipe the previously rendered boxes as well. Yeah, there are 3 or 4 methods for clearing the canvas and their performance varies a bit with each browser version... but it's all a matter of nanoseconds.

Comment: Also, another reason for clearing the whole canvas is because when the boxes overlap, the top one will erase a part of the bottom one (see in my snippet how the blue one always erases a part of the red one). This can be solved by checking whether something else is drawn in the clean area, but in my opinion it's just not worth it as it can get ridiculously complicated as the number of objects increase.