# Moving the same circle at the same time independently javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using html and javascript to make a game and i have been stuck on this for a while this section of code is all about making a enemy move from one side of the screen to the other is not the problem as i have done it with other characters. The big problem is that i cant clone them and make them move independently.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var h = canvas.height;
var w = canvas.width;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = w
var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 1);

clear();
circleE();

function clear(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "Blue"
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h)
}

function circleE(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "Pink";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,y,15,0,Math.PI*2,false);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since they share x and y coordinates, all clones would be rendered in the exact same space. Each of the circles needs to have its own coordinates.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var h = canvas.height;
    var w = canvas.width;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    clear();
   
    function clear(){
        ctx.fillStyle = "Blue"
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h)
    }

    function circleE(){
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * w) + 1);
        var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * h) + 1);
        ctx.fillStyle = "Pink";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,15,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="circleE()">Spawn</button><br>
<canvas id="canvas" height="200" width="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: how would i do that i tried an array but i failed what would u suggest

Comment: Depends on how complex you want to go, and what the circles need to do. I simply randomized the x and y in my snippet, but you can create a circle object, and each object would have coordinates as their properties. That's what you'd ideally do in case you're animating multiple circles, etc.

Comment: Long ago, I wrote an answer to a question not similar to yours, but the actual solution might help you, see it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34265601/965907